# BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() is failing to receive the broadcast sent by another BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a `Service` from where I send a broadcast `intent` to a `BroadcastReceiver` and then this broadcast receiver sends it back to a `BroadcastReceiver` specified inside the `Service`.

Here's the code:

```
private Notification getNotificationAU() {
        mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon_1)
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setContentText(***);

        // for action button
        Intent actionIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BroadcastSender.class);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
                        0, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.addAction(***, "***", actionPendingIntent);
        return mBuilder.build();
    }
```

Here's `BroadcastSender.class` code:

```
public class BroadcastSender extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Received by BroadcastSender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // send back to your class
        Intent newIntent = new Intent();
        newIntent.setAction(context.getString(R.string.broadcast_id));
        context.sendBroadcast(newIntent);
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast sent back.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

**both** the `Toasts` above is getting shown.

Here's `BroadcastReceiver` inside the `Service`:

```
    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public MyBroadcastReceiver(){
            super();
        }

        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive() in service called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(getString(R.string.broadcast_id_2))) {
               ...
               ...
               ...
        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(getString(R.string.broadcast_id))) {

                // perform the task

        } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Intent is null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    }
```

Here's the `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="broadcast_id">***</string>
```

Here's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastSender"/>
```

**The problem is** that `MyBroadcastReceiver` is not receiving any broadcast even when both have same broadcast id `R.string.broadcast_id`.

Why it isn't receiving the broadcast sent by `BroadcastSender.class`?

Please let me know.

Comment: how you register and unregister broadcast receiver ? can you show that code

Comment: can you also paste the code of where you have registered the MyBroadcastReceiver in your service ?

Comment: Thanks for finding out this silly mistake! I forgot to add `myIntentFilter.addAction(getString(R.string.broadcast_id));` while registering the broadcast receiver. It works now!

Comment: welcome brother

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept that answer. It will remove this question from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @DavidWasser done. Please see the answer below.

Comment: @HasifSeyd and Jitesh can you please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41356178/6144372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was not adding the line `myIntentFilter.addAction(getString(R.string.broadcast_id));` while registering the `BroadcastReceiver`.

It got solved after adding the line.

Thanks to [Jitesh Mohite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5106574/jitesh-mohite) and [Hasif Seyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3012602/hasif-seyd) for helping me finding out this small but crucial mistake.