# Why notifications are getting fired multiple times on retrieving data from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I have a button, when I press it some data is fetched from `FirebaseDatabase` and then a `notification` is fired.

Here's how:

```
aReference.child(rID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
            Map<String, String> newRequest = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            uAU = newRequest.get("pName");  

            final int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION, getNotificationAU());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), m, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
});
```

Here's `NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.class`:

```
public class NotificationARBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";
    public static NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;
    public static int m;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        m = (new Random()).nextInt(10000);
        Log.d("mMain", String.valueOf(m));


        mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        mNotifyMgr.cancel(m);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(m, notification);

    }
}
```

Here's `getNotificationAU()`:

```
private Notification getNotificationAU() {
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon_1)
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setContentText(***);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    return mBuilder.build();
}
```

**The problem** is that on pressing the button even once, notifications are fired multiple times and many same notifications are shown in the status bar.

**Why** is this happening and how to fire only one notification?

Please let me know.

Comment: looks like you have multiple child under `aReference.child(rID)`, new notification is shown every `onChildAdded` is called

Comment: @Wilik yes there are multiple child. So, how can I show the notification just once even under this circumstance?

Comment: it depends on your notification purpose, you can use ValueEventListener instead, set the same id for every notification, or check if a notification is shown before firing new one.

Comment: you should check whether notification is shown before firing up, actually it depends on your logic.

Comment: how to check whether notification is shown before?

Comment: you have multiple child? and for every child you are trying to show different notification or the notification is same for all child ?

Comment: @HasifSeyd notification is same for all child

Comment: then instead of using random id each time you show notification (new Random()).nextInt(10000), make it same id ,use some constant value

Comment: [How to check which notifications are active in status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630733/how-to-check-which-notifications-are-active-in-status-bar-in-android-dev)

Comment: to check if notification is present,from API 23 you can use this method  NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications(). This returns a list of active notifications launched by your app in a form of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `mNotifyMgr.cancelAll();` (where `mNotifyMgr` is the `NotificationManager`) before `mNotifyMgr.notify(m, notification);` did the job for me!